# Laravel 5 build with Sximo

Tags: php, css, laravel, backend

Helou, I'm frontend developer and my PHP knowledge is on begginers level. I have Laravel Site build with Sximo by other developer. I need to add a new .css and .js files for **backend** platform, but I don't know where. I added to public folder these files, but don't know how to call them. Can anyone help me?

P. S. No, I can't add it manuel, it's not for frontend page. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question in the current form is not a good fit. SO is for concrete questions. If you have problems getting this to work, please add your more details to the question and describe as precisely as possible what does not work and how it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all `.js` and `.css` files into a `public` directory inside of your Laravel project directory:

```
public/css/my.css
public/js/mybig.js
```

Please read here how to add them to a view (recipe valid for Laravel 4 apps and Laravel 5 apps with Laravel Collective installed):

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/184/generating-a-link-to-a-css-file

Also, I think you'd want to learn about how [Blade Template](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) system works.

Comment: Yes, when is Laravel 5, you are correct. But it's build with SXIMO, masterview.blade.php is not the same, it's only containts <div class="sximo-box"></div> and other code inside it. No <html> tags, no <body> tags. And I want to edit SXIMO Backend code. No frontend.